# Lua & Javascript documentation generation

Tags: javascript, documentation, lua

I am in the beginning phase of create a mobile MMO with my team. The server software will be written in JavaScript using NodeJS, and the client software in Lua using Corona. We need a tool to auto-generate documentation for both the server-side and client-side code.

Are there any tools which can generate documentation for both Lua and Javascript? And as a bonus: we are hosting our project on Bitbucket and the Bitbucket Wiki uses the Creole markup language. So if it's possible I want the tool to export to Creole.

Edit: I know about tools for generating documentation for one of both languages. However, I don't want 2 different styles for documentation in one project. Therefore one tool which can generate documentation for both languages would be great.

Comment: I don't know any tool for both of them. But for Lua there is [LuaDoc](http://keplerproject.github.com/luadoc/). And a little googling led me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818875/is-there-a-way-to-generate-javascript-api-documentation-like-the-google-closure) at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am really looking for a tool which can do both. I'd like to have a uniform documentation style, and if I use 2 different tools then I will have 2 different styles of documentation.

Comment: I understand, but if you don't mind, I'd like to share a thought: From your point of view, this make sense: 1 style fits all documentation. From my point of view, if I'm working with Lua, I expect the documentation in Luadoc-style. If I'm working with Java, I expect the documentation on JavaDoc-style. If I'm working with .Net, in MSDN-style, and so on. My (uninformed) opinion is that an "one-style-fits-all" documentation does not make your API easier to use to a new developer.

Comment: I agree with you. We end up using LuaDoc and JSDoc. They are quite similar and this was the closest we could get to an ideal solution without writing our own document generator.

Answer (score 1):

[Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/index.html) currently only does Javascript but it includes a [modular system](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html#more-domains) to add new languages. Maybe not the simpler solution but with some work it would be usable with the two languages.

As a reference, [Erlang extension file](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/afa07a97ea628044d8b9f6700d22ed8c3d67715f/erlangdomain/sphinxcontrib/erlangdomain.py?at=default) is written in ~400 LOC.

[python-creole](https://code.google.com/p/python-creole/) allow conversion between Creole and reStructuredText (via HTML).